# How to pass JS object to PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, object

```
$('.select_category').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var ID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo site_url($this->config->item('admin_folder').'/catalog/get_all_option');?>',
                type:'POST',
                data:{category_id:1},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){

                    $('#attribute_form').html('<?php add_attribute_form("'+data+'");?>');


                }

            });
        }

    });
```

on callback function success return the data and pass it to add_attribute_form(data) php function but nothing response.
what is the correct way to pass js object to php function

Comment: Hum, you can't call a PHP function like that. After the page is already rendered in the browser, you just can't do that. You have to do what your function does using JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: but it work fine when i pass the custom data like add_attribute_form('yasir') and it show on #attribute_form div But i actually pass the object to the function.

Comment: What you need to know is that the instructions inside the PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`) are carried out *before* the page is transferred to the user agent, so you'll never see a PHP tag in the delivered page! and the `add_attribute_form()` function will also be carried out before hand, no matter you pass the `yasir` or the `'+data+'` as the argument for the PHP function!!

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to do here is, use Ajax to send data to a **separate** php page passing it some information, then, based on that information, the php page should **return** data to the Ajax callback function which will add the returned data to the original page.

#### Here's a simple example [(and a working demo here)](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/returntest/index.html):

In `index.html` do this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.select_category').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var ID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'somepage.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{category_id:1},
                dataType: 'json', // this setting means you expect the server to return json formatted data
                                  // this is important because if the data you get back is not valid json, 
                                  // the success callback below will not be called, 
                                  // the error callback will be called instead
                success:function(response){
                    $('#attribute_form').html(response.html); 
                    // if not using json, this would just be $('#attribute_form').html(response); 
                },
                error:function(xhr, status, error){
                   // handel error 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="select_category"> Check this box
<div id="attribute_form"></div>
```

Then in `somepage.php` do the following:

```
<?php
$category_id = isset($_POST['category_id']) ? $_POST['category_id'] : null;
if($category_id == '1'){
    echo json_encode(array('html'=>'<h1>This text came from the php page</h1>'));
    exit;
    
    // if you are not using dataType:json in your ajax, you can just do:
    // echo '<h1>This text came from the php page</h1>';
    // exit;
}
?>
```